# How to display Starting at price?

Tags: price, catalog-price-rules, tierprice, price-rules

Maybe a stupid question, but how do I display the "Starting at:" price?

Inside price.phtml I see this line

```
<?php if ($showMinPrice): ?>
```

But I cannot find the setting inside the admin panel.

Comment: I think that 'Starting at' will be displayed if product has at least one option with price. I can be wrong.

Comment: When you want to show Bundle Product, Magento will display price in "From: $10.00 To $20.00" format automatically. If you want to change the label "From:" to "Starting at:" you can use  translate.csv of theme to rename it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no setting to enable or disable this, it will be displayed automatically depending on the product.

"Starting at" will be displayed for a group product and will show the lowest price from the simple products associated to the parent product. "As low as" will be displayed when tier prices exist for simple or configurable products.

You can however modify price.phtml to change the way lowest priced products or tier prices are displayed by extending the base theme, or modifying your existing themes price.phtml template file.